# How to unlock Gnome Keyring after passwordless login with Solokey (Yubiko)?

Tags: pam, fido-u2f

I experimented on a Ubuntu 19.04 system a bit and took a look here: 
https://schulz.dk/2019/08/23/using-solokey-for-linux-login/
and here:
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Pam#Advanced_configuration

After this created a file named common-fido-auth and included it in

```
/etc/pam.d/sudo
```

and 
    /etc/pam.d/gdm-password

The last one looks like this

```
#%PAM-1.0
session required pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session required pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
@include common-fido-auth #instead of @include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

I assumed that common-auth has modules which unlocks the gnome keyring and copied some lines from common-auth

```
auth include common-fido
auth requisite pam_deny.so
auth required pam_permit.so
auth optional pam_cap.so
```

Where as common-fido looks like

```
auth sufficient pam_u2f.so
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

But it seems to be wrong. The pam_unix.so is not interpereted properly and with the Solokey I have to type in my password for the Gnome Keyring

Has someone any ideas?

Comment: I m having the same problem. Using Fedora MATE 31. Key changes I made are:

`# diff passwd passwd.bk0 
4c4
< password   optional pam_gnome_keyring.so use_authtok
---
> -password   optional pam_gnome_keyring.so use_authtok
# diff lightdm lightdm.bk0
3d2
< auth       sufficient  pam_u2f.so authfile=/etc/u2f_mappings cue
6c5
< auth       optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so
---
> -auth       optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so
21c20
< session    optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
---
> -session    optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start`

but still no luck.

Comment: MAybe this helps. Had a longer discussion here: https://github.com/Yubico/pam-u2f/issues/130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a project which solves this by creating a file with the encrypted password for the keyring in a form that can be automatically decrypted using the hardware dongle.

https://github.com/recolic/gnome-keyring-yubikey-unlock

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in https://github.com/Yubico/pam-u2f/issues/130, that Twinkybot referenced above, GNOME Keyring requires a password to unlock, so if you log using other means, there's no way to have the password provided to the GNOME Keyring daemon by pam.

Alternatives include:

- Leaving the password blank. This does mean what's stored in the keyring is no longer encrypted.
- Encrypt the password using keys stored on your security key (GPG or PIV), so if you have it plugged in for login, a script can automatically unlock your keyring with the file holding the encrypted password.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!