# How to unlock kdewallet with FIDO2 key

Tags: kde, pam, fido-u2f

I am using a FIDO2 key to login into my KDE session, but then KDE wallet asks for a password. I am using it and find it quite useful to keep keys, ssh passwords, etc in one place.
Is there a way to unlock it with FIDO2 key? Or may be there is a replacement wallet that works with FIDO2 ?

Comment: Hi, same issue here. I do not think that there is a mechanism for that in KDE Wallet right now, maybe the GNOME keyring does, if you are using GDM, it should unlock that. If there was a mechanism for that, it should be in the relevant PAM file, but it needs backend support as well. One way now is deleting your KDE wallet subsystem and use GDM or it's relevant PAM configuration in your desired login manager. I have already made a bug report for it, it seems it is assigned to a developer: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=476095 I hope this helps somewhat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot unlock your kwallet with FIDO2, because the wallet is encrypted with your password by default. If you do a passwordless login with FIDO2, then your password has not been entered and kwallet cannot be unlocked on login.

For reference, GNOME Keyring has the same issue, see: [How to unlock Gnome Keyring after passwordless login with Solokey (Yubiko)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551021/how-to-unlock-gnome-keyring-after-passwordless-login-with-solokey-yubiko)

Current password managers and keyring software like GNOME Keyring, KWallet, KeePass and Bitwarden use passwords to encrypt their databases. So they do not support passwordless unlocking. Passwordless support is coming soon to Bitwarden, and may be available in other products. It will be a while before (if?) it becomes possible with GNOME Keyring and KWallet.

From what I have gathered (I have the same issue), Linux systems generally use the PAM system to handle logins. Many distros are set up with PAM modules for the system keyring ― GNOME Keyring (`pam_gnome_keyring`) and KWallet (`pam_kwallet5`) ― to be unlocked on login. With KWallet, it's the `kwalletd5` daemon that is called for unlocking by the `pam_kwallet5` PAM module.

The *How to unlock GNOME Keyring* link above mentions a way to unlock the keyring using a Yubico Key with PGP. But FIDO2-only keys don't support PGP/GPG. There is no way to use a FIDO2-only key to unlock a keyring that is password-encrypted. FIDO2 does not provide passwords: it provides a way to validate credentials.

The following does not answer the OP, but I would say the best bet is to use a secret manager meant to be used unattended by automated systems. We could use it to store the login password, and (like the post linked above) launch a script on login to unlock the kwallet. Or course, this method adds a security risk since you need to store somewhere the credentials for the secrets manager. Someone with access to your session could then retrieve your password.

Two products I have in mind:

- [Bitwarden Secrets Manager](https://bitwarden.com/help/secrets-manager-overview/) (I already have a Bitwarden Premium plan)
- [passage](https://github.com/FiloSottile/passage) with [age](https://github.com/FiloSottile/age) for a free and simple solution

**Update**: `age` does not support SSH keys of type `ecdsa-sk` or `ed25519-sk`. So securing a `passage` password database with FIDO2 SSH credentials is not an option.

> Instead of storing on disk the credentials for the secrets manager, the FIDO2 key could be used. The `age` encryption tool supports encrypting to SSH keys as recipients, and OpenSSH now supports creating SSH key pairs with FIDO2 secure keys. Instead of storing credentials for `passage` on disk, we could possibly use FIDO2 keys (I would make sure to encrypt for 2 FIDO2 keys, otherwise you would have no way to unlock `passage` if you loose your FIDO2 key.) I have not tested this yet.

However I have not found how to unlock a kwallet by script. `kwalletd5` provides no help. I am thinking I could replace KWallet with GNOME Keyring or KeePassXC.

Comment: Certain FIDO2 keys have a HMAC feature that _could_ be used to protect secrets; systemd-cryptenroll uses that for LUKS volume keys. I don't know whether it would be feasible to integrate that with kwallet.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It was my understandanding that FIDO2 could not be used in this manner. I found this question that provides some clues how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72561218/fido2-authentication-for-offline-net-application. I will dig a little more.

Comment: Originally it could not; this is an extension feature.

Comment: Luckily, my HyperFIDO Pro Mini seems to support the `hmac-secret` extension.

Comment: As for 'age', the reason it doesn't support `-sk` keys is the same reason why it does not support ssh-agent – all "normal" SSH (as well as FIDO2) operations only involve signing, not decryption, so both ssh-agent and FIDO keys only provide a way to _sign_ something with an SSH key, but not a way to decrypt anything with it. When age has direct access to the private key material, it can use it for decryption (IIRC, by transforming the ECDSA key to an ECDH key), but it can't do that through a 'sign' operation. (I think it _might_ be possible with RSA, though, but of course FIDO doesn't do RSA.)